# Activating virtualenv in a Python script

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualenv

I have a Python script named `runner.py` that needs to be run at a VM with no chances of installing new python libraries at the moment of execution, as Internet is disabled.

As I have the img of the VM, I have given it LAN, installed virtualenv and created a virtualenv at `/tmp/myenv`.
As this VM is a snapshot, I lose all data inside when it boots (each 10 minutes), including temp.
I have kept a copy of that venv created at my computer.

When VM is launched, I can launch it with files at `/home/user1/myfolder` and then it runs `runner.py`

`runner.py` is executed via the default python binaries at `/bin/python` and is supposed to:

1. Do some stuff
2. Copy  myfolder/myenv to /tmp/myenv (As it wasn't there).
3. Activate it.
4. And finally run 2 Python scripts (arguments like -n or -t can vary) that redirect the output to a text file `output.out`:

   ./scritp1.py -n 200 -t 0.01 | ./script2.py > output.out
5. Continue doing other stuff, like an analysis of output.out.

My doubts are between step 2 and 3, I don't know how to **activate** the virtual environment and continue with the normal execution of the script.

### Questions

- Is it possible to make it in Python itself?
- If not, I have seen that it is possible to make a `run_program.sh` to handle steps 2 and 3 at the same time, but I have no idea of how to.

Comment: it should be enough if you use `#!/tmp/myenv/bin/python` shebang in `./script1.py` and `./script2.py` i.e., you could omit step 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to activate the `virtualenv`; it should be enough just to run the scripts using virtualenv python binary e.g., `/tmp/myenv/bin/python`.

You can activate virtualenv for the shell command:

```
. /tmp/myenv/bin/activate && ./scritp1.py -n 200 -t 0.01 | ./script2.py > output.out
```

It works if `./script1.py` uses `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang or equivalent.